# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio dbcreator permission

Tags: sql, sql-server

RE: Permissions

Program - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v.17.1

When attempting to create a new database through Object Explorer, I get the following error:

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA9mf.png)

To fix this, I did the following and got another error:

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzLCl.png)

I have searched the internet and all posts and articles say that I need to log in as administrator or `SA`. I am logged in as administrator and still can not gain permission to create a database.

How do I assign permission to the `SA` account to create a new database?

Comment: You have two accounts in your screenshot, builtin\users and sa. Are you logged in as sa? If not, you don't have permission to perform these actions. You need to login as sa and then do so.

Comment: I guess I assumed i was logged in as SA because it says "(Administrator)" in the title toolbar.  You can see it in image 2.

Comment: I log in using Authentication: Windows Authentication.  Do I have to use SQL Server Authentication to do what I want to accomplish?  BTW - I don't know what that password is or I would try it.

Comment: Whoever installed SQL server set up the "sa" account. It's a unique login for every SQL server install. That person has the password and that is what you need. Windows administrators have no power here.

Comment: And the reason you are able to log in as the "Administrator" is because, by default, it's part of the BUILTIN\USERS group, via proxy of Authenticated Users, to which each user that logs into the computer is a part of. If you look at the permissions for BUILTIN\USERS login, you will surely see that they do not have the ability to create databases. Which user can give the BUILTIN\USERS permissions? You guessed it--sa.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion for you is that you are using a windows login and SQL has it's own logins as well. You can see where this is specified in the drop down menu at the login screen. You can use both SQL and windows logins if you configure SQL for both when you install. SA is the default "S"QL "A"dmin login. The full admin user in SQL. Cannot add or remove SA permissions (hence why you are getting errors trying to modify them). Until you add other logins and give them permissions, SA is the only user that can do pretty much anything useful in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is that you are logged in with the local Windows Administrator account. You have two logins for your SQL Server instance as can be seen in your Image #2. One is SA (SQL Admin). The other is BUILTIN\USERS. That is a default group which every user that logs into the machine will be a part of. But unless you give that group permissions, or create other logins (I recommend this), you will be very limited to what you can do.

As you have found, that user group cannot modify permissions, especially for the SA user. The SA user is special, you cannot modify SA permissions at all. This is why you are receiving errors (partly because you don't have permissions to change them with the user you are logged in as, and partly because SA permissions cannot be modified).

The resolution to your issue is to login with the SA account. You will need to choose "SQL Login" at the login screen, as opposed to Windows login. SSMS will prompt you for a password. This password was configured by the person who installed the SQL instance. If the person who installed SQL Server did not specify a password, it will be most likely be a blank password or "Password123".

Once you are logged into the SA account, you can create new SQL *or* Windows Authentication logins and and provision them permissions as needed.